# Python nested loop over-printing

Tags: python

I am coding a program with two arrays of 4 arrays of information. One with male names, female names, and their respective rankings (context is confusing.) Its basically two arrays with the same length and each number corresponds to the name in that spot. I know I should use a 2D array but I haven't learnt that yet.

Here is the sample code.

```
namesM = ['Nathan', 'Jacob', 'Sam']

rankingsM =[100,200,20] 

namesF = ['Sarah','Beth', 'Sam']

rankingsF = [233,5456,246]
```

My problem is this:

```
for i in range(len(namesM)):
  #print("%s (%d)" %(namesM[i], rankingsM[i]))
  for j in range(len(namesF)):
    if namesM[i]==namesF[j]:
      print("%s (%d, %d)" %(namesF[j],rankingsM[i], rankingsF[j]))
```

I want the code to print out the names in this way

```
name (amount)
```

If the men and women arrays have the same name on them, it should print

```
name (amount1, amount2)
```

It should look something like this in the end:

```
Nathan (100) 

Jacob (200) 

Sam (246, 20)

Sarah (233)

Beth (5456)
```

I cant figure out how to print it properly. Any help?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, and can you fix the indentation issues in your code?

Comment: What you NEED is a dictionary.  The key would be a name, the value would be a list of rankings.  Just run through the two pairs of lists and fill in names.

Comment: I agree with Tim Roberts, dictionaries are the way to go. **If** you need to have male and female names separated, perhaps use two dictionaries with the keys as names and amounts as values. You could then check for a name existing in the other dictionary with something like `if name in dict_2:`.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine both name lists into one, and both rankings lists into one, then you can [`zip`](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/#zip) those two master lists together and iterate over them to build a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), finding duplicates as you go. Each key in the dictionary will be a name, and each value will be a list of scores (even if the list only contains one score).

```
namesM = ['Nathan', 'Jacob', 'Sam']
rankingsM =[100, 200, 20] 

namesF = ['Sarah', 'Beth', 'Sam']
rankingsF = [233, 5456, 246]

names = namesM + namesF
rankings = rankingsM + rankingsF

names_and_rankings = {}
for name, rank in zip(names, rankings):
    if name in names_and_rankings:
        names_and_rankings[name].append(rank)
    else:
        names_and_rankings[name] = [rank]
```

Then you can iterate over the dictionary's [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), which gives you both the keys and values, convert the rankings into strings with a simple [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/), [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them together with commas when needed, and print your desired output with an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
for name, ranks in names_and_rankings.items():
    ranks = ', '.join([str(i) for i in ranks])
    print(f'{name} ({ranks})')
```

This outputs:

```
Nathan (100)
Jacob (200)
Sam (20, 246)
Sarah (233)
Beth (5456)
```

---

If you're interested in some slightly more advanced techniques, you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify the dictionary creation:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# ...

names_and_rankings = defaultdict(list)
for name, rank in zip(names, rankings):
    names_and_rankings[name].append(rank)
```

And lastly, this may not matter for your use case. But if your lists are quite large, it's inefficient to create those two new lists, `names` and `rankings`, that duplicate all your values. In that case you could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Instead of creating entirely new lists in memory, this simply iterates over your existing lists in order, one after another.

```
from itertools import chain

# ...

names = chain(namesM, namesF)
rankings = chain(rankingsM, rankingsF)
```

Answer (score -1):

Without using defaultdict:

```
data = {}
for name,rank in zip(namesM, rankingsM):
    if name not in data:
        data[name] = []
    data[name].append(rank)
for name,rank in zip(namesF, rankingsF):
    if name not in data:
        data[name] = []
    data[name].append(rank)
print(data)
```

Shorter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
for name,rank in zip(namesM, rankingsM):
    data[name].append(rank)
for name,rank in zip(namesF, rankingsF):
    data[name].append(rank)
print(data)
```